# action server vs publisher + service

Tags: ros, action, actionlib, ros-service, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When would you use a Publisher + Service Node vs an Action Node? As far as I can tell they seem equivalent, besides the fact that anything can subscribe to the publisher, while only the client gets data back from an Action server.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248778/action-server-vs-publisher-+-service/) by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2016-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While both use topics to communicate, conceptually (basic) pub/sub and Action client/servers are definitely not equivalent.

Pub/sub is used to enable dataflow between producers and any number of consumers with the middleware in between to broker the connections. There is a clear unidirectional flow of data, and no synchronisation coupling between sender and receiver(s). This way of communication is sometimes called *fire-and-forget* (as senders do not care about what happens to their messages).

Action client-server communication is essentially a client-server *service* interaction pattern, but with the *option* of making that interaction *asynchronous* (ie: no forced control flow synchronisation between client and server) and implemented on-top of the pub/sub pattern. Asynchronicity is an option, as the Action infrastructure allows servers to periodically update clients of the status of the operation(s) they are performing by sending them *feedback*. A final piece of feedback is used to communicate the *result* of an operation to the client. By blocking until reception of the completion notification, Actions become synchronous (ie: flow of control between client and server is coupled for the duration of the operation). By ignoring the feedback, Actions are completely asynchronous. In all cases clients may request the server to abort processing its request. Likening this to pub/sub described above, Actions would be something like *fire-and-get-notified-on-completion-if-you-want*.

The [wiki/actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) has a good write-up on this as well.

Actions are like the `std::promise` and `std::future` facilities in C++11 or the Python 3 asynchronous coroutines.

For quite some systems I believe it would be beneficial to always implement services as Actions (unless the services are really trivial), as client-server synchronisation is a choice when using Actions, but inherent for services.

---

Edit: a paper with a nice overview of the different interaction patters (but with a focus on publish-subscribe) is [*The many faces of publish-subscribe*](https://doi.org/10.1145/857076.857078), by Eugster et al. (publicly accessible copy [here](http://www.eurecom.fr/fr/publication/1211/detail/the-many-faces-of-publish-subscribe)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5